# Choose class depending on external input in C++

Tags: c++, templates

In my program I have several different classes containing a function with the same name, but different output:

```
#include <iostream>

#define CLASS_TO_USE C

class A{
public:
    std::string class_name = "Class A";

    A()
    {};

    double add(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

class B{
public:
    std::string class_name = "Class B";

    B()
    {};

    double add(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        return 2 * a + b;
    }
};


class C{
public:
    std::string class_name = "Class C";

    C()
    {};

    double add(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        return 3 * a + b;
    }
};

template <class T>
void calculate_addition(const T &local_class, const double a, const double b)
{
    std::cout << "Addition gives the value " << local_class.add(a, b) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    CLASS_TO_USE local_class;
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    calculate_addition(local_class, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Currently I switch between those classes by changing the variable for `CLASS_TO_USE`, but that method requires recompilation, which takes some time. I would instead prefer a method which works during runtime, i.e. where I can use f.ex. the input from the user. Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Edit: I solved the problem using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

class A{
public:
    std::string class_name_string = "Class A";

    A()
    {};

    virtual double add(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        (void) a;
        (void) b;
        return 0;
    };

    virtual std::string class_name(void) const
    {
        return class_name_string;
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    std::string class_name_string = "Class B";

    B()
    {};

    double add(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        return 2 * a + b;
    }

    virtual std::string class_name(void) const
    {
        return class_name_string;
    }
};


class C : public A{
public:
    std::string class_name_string = "Class C";

    C()
    {};

    double add(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        return 3 * a + b;
    }

    virtual std::string class_name(void) const
    {
        return class_name_string;
    }
};

class D : public A{
public:
    std::string class_name_string = "Class D";

    D()
    {};

    double add(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    virtual std::string class_name(void) const
    {
        return class_name_string;
    }
};

void calculate_base_addition(const A &local_class, const double a, const double b)
{
    std::cout << "Addition gives the value " << local_class.add(a, b) << " by using " << local_class.class_name() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    A *base_class;
    B tmp_class_B;
    C tmp_class_C;
    D tmp_class_D;
    int class_to_choose = 2;
    switch(class_to_choose)
    {
    case 0:
    {
        base_class = &tmp_class_B;
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        base_class = &tmp_class_C;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    default:
    {
        base_class = &tmp_class_D;
        break;
    }
    }
    std::cout << "Name of base_class: " << (*base_class).class_name() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Name of derived class: " << tmp_class_B.class_name() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    calculate_base_addition(*base_class, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

and have a follow-up question here: [Define class variable in class based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51363033)

Comment: Same signature, different body: inheritance

Comment: The runtime answer is to use inheriotance: a virtual method in a base class. You will need a switch statement or similar to choose which class to construct, but then refer to it using a base class pointer.

Comment: @RichardCritten: So, create a base class containing all functions, derive children classes from it, and then I can use a pointer to the base class, filling it with the derived class?

Comment: Yes.  You can also pass a command-line parameter in to say what derived class to create and as @GemTaylor said use a switch statement to implement the instantiation.

Comment: Pity I couldn't spell inheritance... but there you go!

Comment: @RichardCritten or `std::variant<A, B, C>`

Comment: @Caleth: Can not use variant, unfortunately, due to being limited to C++14

Comment: @RichardCritten: Assumed I would like to use this class in a second class as variable: Should I edit the question, or should I open a new question?

Comment: I would lean toward making the virtual member function be `operator()`, depending on how it fits into a non-toy problem. I say that particularly because this isn’t really just addition.

Comment: @Ben: Do you have an example for that?

Comment: You literally just declare the function `double operator()(const double a, const double b) const` then instead of calling `local_class.add(a, b);` you call `local_class(a, b);` then we’d refer to `local_class` as a function object. At least in your example, I’d advocate this since the class exists just to call a function. If it had other methods that did other things then I’d reconsider.

Comment: @Ben: The example was supposed to be a simple version of my problem, in my real code each class contains ~thirty different functions doing calculations. Thus I am not sure if your approach would work

Comment: @Ben: An extended question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51363033

Comment: @RichardCritten: I used your suggestion, thus if you add an answer, I can accept that and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dispatch on an integer user input e.g. like this:

```
int choice;

std::cin >> choice;

switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        calculate_addition(A(), 2, 3);
        break;
    case 2:
        calculate_addition(B(), 2, 3);
        break;
    case 3:
    default:
        calculate_addition(C(), 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: That works fine if the classes only contain one or two functions, for ~thirty it becomes a bit confusing, I think...

Comment: Hm, I don't get why the number of member functions increases the complexity?! Isn't the number of classes responsible for how ugly the switch dispatching is?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, did you mean to create a new function called `calculate_addition(choice, a, b)`?

Comment: No, the snippet would rather go into the main function.

Comment: Ok, on second thought it would work, but unfortunately not in my program. Inheritance would, though. Thanks!